# Conditional formatting to chart axis

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have a chart based on a table.
The data in the table is conditionally formatted to be either a number or currency.

When formatted as a plain number the Y axis looks like the following:

[image]

When formatted as currency the Y axis does not adopt the same formatting. Is this deliberate or a bug in Excel? Is there a workaround? I don't want to use VBA in the solution but any sort of formula is of course fine.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit - Actual Solution:

The solution to this tricky thing was to use named ranges!

A named range can switch his content, thereby redirecting a chart dynamically based on a condition! This is quite powerful. I used it on other occasions, but I had to first get really obsessed with this question, so that my memory was triggered.

In my screenshot you see all contents to solve this. Just set up those two names with a condition you like.

Unfortunately my solution requires to dublicate your data-columns in order to reflect the different formattings. But at least, it solves your problem.

[image: solution with named ranges]

---

Edit:

After looking into this problem more detailed, I must mark here, that my answer does not solves this particular problem. While this can be used in combination with a VBA-Solution for the given problem, it cannot be applied without VBA, except of course for static formatted data.

---

This is possible with the right settings for your axis:

[image]

When you link to source, the formatting of your data will be reflected in your diagram ;)

Otherwise your chart will use whatever format you have set for this axis.

Comment: Thanks for this: the question specifically mentions `conditional formatting` - this answer doesn't work.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not get that you did know this and it just does not work with cond. formattig. Have you too tried some VBA solution, which did or did not worked eighter? Do you mind a VBA-solution?

Comment: I've been using VBA for 10yrs - was hoping to solve this via finctions

Comment: ok, looked deeper into this, but there seems not to be any way to get to the conditional format of a cell or the chart-axis numberformat (except mybe some menu-hopping-code) - not via VBA, not via function. So, because of that, I would say, you'll have to replicate your format condition and use additional cols with a formular like `=IF(COND;TEXT(0.00$);TEXT(0.00))`. At least that is it for me, happy to see another solution :)

Comment: please amend your answer with a full explanation of what you have just put in this comment - I don't understand your comment and need a full explanation (preferably with screenshots) The bounty is yours then - if it works!

Comment: ok, I did not look deep enough. I am very sorry, but there really seems to be no-way to do this without VBA, because you can't change a cells defined format without out it, and TEXT() makes your numbers to text, so they can't be used to sum up your values in a chart. Tried any other way I could think of, came up empty. Quite the trick question, seemed soooo easy.

Comment: aparently the bounty will get awarded - which is a ridiculous system; these questions should be reviewed by moderators or people with X rep points and a decision made by them.; you have tried the most out of anyone on here.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional formatting does not apply to any graphs, it shows only in the tables in your sheet. It is more of a layer than actual data source.
Use standard currency formatting or you can use a formula like `=a1&" £"` if you need to do some extra data formatting

Comment: this turns the number into text and then the chart is _even_ more confused!

Comment: while conditional formatting does not apply to graphs directly, but by using `Linked to source` you will have the same effects, except for any color-specific stuff, but all data-formats, like data, %, currency, etc.

Comment: @Jook an exception is `conditional formatting` (as specified in the original post). If the format of data changes via conditional formatting then this isn't reflected on the axis even if `Linked to source` is checked.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.excelbanter.com/showthread.php?t=259075) is a link that may help you.  You can do it using Named Ranges and Offset.  That is the best I could find after a little searching.

Comment: I've briefly read through the post and can not see a definitive answer - if you have read this and believe there's an answer in there can you please add the details to your post