# VBA to save a sheet to a password protected PDF

Tags: excel, pdf-generation, excel-2010, vba

The following saves the activesheet as a PDF:

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                               Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                               Filename:="C:\blahblah2.pdf",  _
                               Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                               IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                               OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

I need to be able to create a password protected PDF - is this possible using VBA without buying any additional software?

Comment: See my answer here... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/exceldev/thread/a26cae16-f039-4bb9-9b15-8016b7d0965a

Comment: you've not included all the code in that answer Siddharth but it seems possible to fully automate the process? ... my macro needs to open the PDF, password protect it, close it ...then I have some code to attach the file to an outlook message and send it. I'm just double-checking if I follow your code this is possible? without any manual intervention?

Comment: Just tried to call your name in a totally unrelated question that you haven't answered; not sure if the "@" will mean you see my comment - [SO QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069830/conditional-formatting-to-chart-axis) ....maybe your the last hope for that particular question!

Comment: Sorry. Was busy the entire day will be free only later tonight :) Working on my new website... will answer your questions then :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout no rush on this Siddharth ; look forward to seeing your site.

Comment: @SiddharthRout creating the pdf was loads easier using C#

Comment: Whoops.. This question missed my radar. My sincere apologies. So is your query sorted?

Comment: weird  - the bounty just ran out and Jook solved it; hopefully the next version of xl will not require the solution he has put forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `PDFsharp` using `VS` - my project is in `C#` ... this free library works very well