# (VBA) Convert all excel tabs to each separate protected pdf file

Tags: vba, excel

How to add password into the pdf files which generate from excel?

I have such part of following code:

```
Worksheets(i).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=OutputPath2, _    
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _    
:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

I tried to add

```
Worksheets(i).Protect ("My Password")
```

and alternately

```
ActiveWorkbook.Protect "password",True,True
```

but neither worked.
Does anyone know how to make it work?

Many many thanks!

Comment: thanks your edit, Sameven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no ... Excel itself will not allow you to password protect the exported PDF file.  You have to use an external tool to do so.

See the following for discussion and for alternatives explored: [VBA to save a sheet to a password protected PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373631/vba-to-save-a-sheet-to-a-password-protected-pdf) and see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a26cae16-f039-4bb9-9b15-8016b7d0965a/conerting-excel-into-password-protected-pdf-using-vba?forum=exceldev